# Why are asynchronous XMLHttpRequests preferred over synchronous requests?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

What's the difference between asynchronous and synchronous and how does the difference effect the request?

Comment: It doesn't affect the *request* so much as it affects the browser and, therefore, the experience of the user. A synchronous request causes the browser to more or less "freeze" while waiting for the response.

Comment: Could you explain why you think they're "preferred"? Like every tool, there are good times and bad times to use asynchronous or synchronous requests.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: No, he cannot - otherwise he would not ask :-)

Comment: Since JavaScript runs in the UI thread of the browser, you want to reduce script execution time as much as possible, to avoid freezing the UI. Have you ever seen the popup asking the user whether he wants to cancel the script execution? This happens when a script runs "too long". Synchronous XMLHTTPRequests can be seen `while` loops which break once the response was received. And since network communication is much slower than even program instructions, it is likely that this will result in a long running process.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm absolutely not defending synchronous ajax here, but my impression is that the "slow script" warning happens when JavaScript code actually *runs* for a long time; network delays, in other words, don't count towards that. (I could be wrong; I don't use synchronous ajax so I have literally no experience :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Maybe, I actually don't know either, for the same reason. I didn't necessarily mean that those warnings are also shown for long sync calls. But sync calls can have the same effect as slow scripts. Sometimes I cannot express myself very clearly ;)

Comment: This question is constructive. I disagree with the notion that a constructive and concise question with a definitive answer should be closed or marked as not being a good fit. It answered and helped me solve a problem instead of requiring me to post a too-similar question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Mozilla article on [Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests):

> XMLHttpRequest supports both synchronous and asynchronous communications. In general, however, asynchronous requests should be preferred to synchronous requests for performance reasons.
>
> In short, synchronous requests block the execution of code and can leak memory and events. This can cause serious issues. The only viable reason to use synchronous requests is to more easily facilitate downloads within Web Workers.

Async requests are the main reason why XMLHttpRequest exists. XMLHttpRequest underpins AJAX, the idea of which is to let your JavaScript code run and your user do whatever with your page whilst your JavaScript communicates with the server in the background. Gmail loads your emails this way, for instance.

Synchronous requests block your script from running whilst the transfer completes. Simply put, there's no reason to do this when async requests are available. It would be pretty annoying if your Gmail were freezing up all the time, don't you think? You rarely, if ever, want to use a synchronous request.

[There are circumstances you must use a synchronous request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Irreplaceability_of_the_synchronous_use), but outside of those circumstances you'll likely have absolutely no reason to make a synchronous request, and every reason to use an asynchronous one.

Answer (score 2):

An asynchronous request allows your script to continue running and do something else while it is waiting for the reply from the server.

A synchronous request blocks the execution of the script until a reply is received. That means your application will be unresponsive and can't do anything else.

Comment: In what (apparently rare) circumstances would a synchronous request be more of use to a developer?

Comment: When things need to happen in sequence, or one request depends on the result of another request to be able to run.

Comment: @Mark: Even then are other ways to easily chain async requests (keywords: promises, queues)

Comment: @nima- sync ajax can build a true require, without rewriting all your code to use async techniques. traditional form submits are actually sync, good for displaying a payment approved screen without complex callbacks or multiple HTTP transactions. it's not that js code can't run async, it that as written, some doesn't. that some might be better than nothing or worth the wait.